# How to avoid hcaptcha showing images to solve captcha while using puppeteer for webscraping

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I am trying to scrape a site. But, when i try to pass captcha by pressing on captcha checkmark, it gives me the images to solve the captcha. Sometimes it does that and other times it just passes and navigates me to the page after solving captcha.

Below is the code of how I am setting up my puppeteer instance and page.

```
  puppeteer.use(StealthPlugin());
  
  const chromeOptions = {
    headless: false,
    ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
    slowMo: 30,
    args: ['--no-sandbox'],
  }

  const browser = await puppeteer.launch(chromeOptions);
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.evaluateOnNewDocument(() => {
    delete navigator.__proto__.webdriver;
  });

  await page.setUserAgent(randomUseragent.getRandom());
  await page.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
  //page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(0);
  await page.goto(`pagetoscrape`, {
    waitUntil: "domcontentloaded",
 });
```

And below is how I am trynna solve captcha.

```
  await delay(6000);
  const iframes = await page.$('iframe');
  const frame = await iframes.contentFrame();
  const a = await frame.$('#checkbox');
  await a.click();
  await delay(5000);
  await page.screenshot({path: 'headless-test-result.png'});
  console.log("Solving captcha........");
  await page.waitForNavigation();
  await delay(7000);
```

Comment: From my experience, I can advise you to use any service for solving captcha. The price is more than adequate, of course, if you need it for business, and not for educational purposes.

Answer (score 0):

- The captcha you are trying to solve is type of hCaptcha.
  You can solve that by using following library.

  ```
  https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer-extra-plugin-recaptcha
  ```
- This library is using https://2captcha.com/, you have to purchase paid service then you will get *2CAPTCHA API KEY*. this key is using in code.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-extra');
const StealthPlugin = require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth');
const stealth = StealthPlugin()
stealth.enabledEvasions.delete('user-agent-override')
require('dotenv').config();

const RecaptchaPlugin = require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-recaptcha')

puppeteer.use(
    RecaptchaPlugin({
        provider: {
            id: '2captcha',
            token: 'YOUR 2captcha API KEY', // REPLACE THIS WITH YOUR OWN 2CAPTCHA API KEY ⚡
        },
        visualFeedback: true
    })
)
puppeteer.use(stealth);

(async () => {
    // const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false })
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false,
        args: ['--disable-web-security', '--disable-features=IsolateOrigins,site-per-process']
    })
    const page = await browser.newPage()

    await page.setExtraHTTPHeaders({
        'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,hy;q=0.8'
    });
    const navigationPromise = page.waitForNavigation()

    // Enter app url in browser
    await page.goto('YOUR WEBSITE URL IN WHICH YOU WANT TO SOLVE hCaptcha')

    await navigationPromise

    await page.waitForSelector('.signup_menu_button')
    await page.click('.signup_menu_button')

    await page.waitForSelector('#signup_form_email')
    await page.click('#signup_form_email')
    await page.type('#signup_form_email', 'YOUR EMAIL')

    await page.waitForSelector('#signup_form_password')
    await page.click('#signup_form_password')
    await page.type('#signup_form_password', 'YOUR PASSWORD')

  

    try {
        const captha_response = await page.solveRecaptchas()
        console.log("captha_response: =========***********==========>", captha_response);

        await page.waitFor(500);

        //click on signup to close modal
        await page.evaluate(() => {
            const allDivs = document.querySelectorAll('#signup_button');
            const randomElement = allDivs[Math.floor(Math.random() * allDivs.length)];
            randomElement.click();
        });

        await page.waitForSelector('#signup_button');
        await page.click('#signup_button')

        await page.waitFor(500);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("hcaptcha error==>", err);
    }
})()
```

**Note: This function name is solveRecaptchas(), but it is also solving
hCaptcha also.**